# How can i display my MSI's UI on Uninstalling from a Burn Bootstrapper?

Tags: wix, installation, bootstrapper, burn

I have a Burn bootstrapper which is installing a series of dependency MSIs and then my product MSI.  The main product MSI has `DisplayInternalUI="yes"` which works great and allows me to display custom UI etc etc.

My problem is on uninstall.  I'm making use of the `FilesInUse` dialog in my MSI to prevent uninstall while the application is running.  However this dialog only displays if I uninstall using the MSI.  If I try to uninstall using the bootstrapper the UI will not display.

Is there any way to make the bootstrapper call the MSI with full UI mode on uninstall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Burn doesn't support that. There's typically no support for "full UI on uninstall"; instead, the UI for maintenance mode is shown. That could lead to the user doing something other than uninstall but there'd be no way for Burn to know that what it requested wasn't done.